# Graphics front end for simulator/flowchart/schematic editor in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, simulation, python-3.2, flowchart

I need a mouse driven graphics support for a program such as simulator, schematic editor, flowchart editor, preferably for Python.

It needs to be able to:
-draw, delete, rotate, copy and move lines and simple objects (rectangle, triangle, circle) using mouse
-provide connectors on the objects where the connecting lines get attached
-produce a record of which objects are being connected, so that the simulation can function correctly
-open and save all the chart components/records

Is there such a library or program for Python ? No sense to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an exact match for what you need.  The closest toolsets I can think of are:

- [Flowchart Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flowchartpython/1.1) -- simple charting toolset (non-interactive)
- [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) -- Components for building what you need.
- [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) -- A math and engineering graphics toolset.
- [Tkinter's canvas](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) -- A raw canvas to build tools from scratch.
- [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) -- A widget builder for gaming.

Comment: Know any GTK ones?